# Oneplus 3T Screen and Touch Screen

Tags: broken-screen, oneplus-3

I broke my OnePlus3T the other day.
The screen is cracked, doesn't show anything and the touch screen is not responsive.
This has happened before, but this time I want to fix it myself since it is very expensive to get it fixed.

Since it's my first time trying to fix a phone, I have a these questions:

1) Can an average Joe like me even change a OnePlus3T screen? (Or is it too difficult?)

2) What parts do I need to buy? 
(If I just buy a new screen and apply it, will the touch also be working again, or will I need more than just a new screen?)

3) Is it necessary to buy special equipment? (Or will my average Joe equipment do?)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this video about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sOFwYroAbE). You might be able to find some other ones on Google... For me, it is too difficult to change the screen (any screen, from any phone), and I wouldn't risk it.

It requires as tools (described on the video):

- Plastic Triangle opening tool
- T2 Torx screwdriver
- Nylon Spudger
- A SIM Card ejection tool
- Fine tip curved tweezers
- Precision knife set
- 2mm red adhesive roll
- heat gun
- Professional Phillips Screwdriver
- Cards (playng cards)

I would say most of these equipment will be really necessary, since you will need to perform high precision tasks.